# I wish I'd branched in Git - can I turn back time?

Tags: git

This is a use case which has come up a couple of times. Because I'm (unfortunately) not in the habit of branching for every feature, sometimes I start work on a task, make a couple of commits, and then say "Crap...this is more complicated than I thought...I wish I'd created a branch three commits ago."

At that point, I can go back to a particular commit and branch from there, but that leaves those new commits on the master, and not on the feature branch. I could cherry-pick each commit, or maybe rebase it onto the new branch somehow, but that still leaves the branch commits on the master.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Please refer to the following help document for turning back time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsKbwR7WXN4

Comment: Why not create your feature branch where you are as soon as you realize you need it, then move master back a few commits?

Comment: @jeffdill2 - nice. Or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lc7BAiSh6W0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shortest thing to do:

- create new branch where master is
- reset master back to where you want it:

Suppose you are on master and you realize the last two commits on master should be on a feature branch:

```
git branch feature-A
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

That's it.

Comment: Triple quotes don't work on SO as it does on say GitHub. Use indent-by-four instead (or use the formatting button in the toolbar).

Comment: Thanks for the edition, @MadPhysicist. I actually had taken the time to see what you had done to get the text corrected. Thanks!

Comment: To add a little more info: in git, branches are just **pointers** to revisions and as such they can be placed anywhere you want them (move them back, forward, sideways, switched over, etc).

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing the history here...at this point, aren't there still commits "in the future" on the master? I guess if I make a new commit on master, those are orphaned and GC'ed? And if not, then a merge would just fast-forward...

Comment: Great solution. Worth mentioning though that this is assuming that you haven't already pushed the commits to origin/master.

Comment: after you reset --hard, master will start pointing two revisions "behind" where it was originally (which means that the two commits you wanted to be on the feature branch will only be on the feature branch and master won't have those revisions anymore). Given that after the reset you would still be sitting on top of master branch, if you chose to commit, it will be a new revision on the branch, nothing will be orphaned, (no detached HEAD either). That is assuming (as I said on my response) that you are working on master at the moment.

Comment: @jeffdill2. You don't generally push to master (the branch), you push to origin (the remote), or some other remote. You can always undo a push with `push -f`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeah, I edited my comment. And yes, you can force push but it's important to note that this solution isn't taking that into consideration.